# Como deshabilitar un elemento angular

Tags: html, angular

soy un poco novato en angular, y me han pedido que haga lo siguiente:
tenemos un sistema de permisos, el cual gestionamos de la siguiente manera:

```
<mat-checkbox 
[disabled]="!isPermission('createEvent_rrss', true)">
```

La cosa es que nos han pedido que por rendimiento estos disabled pasen a hacerse de la siguiente forma en el archivo ts del componente=

```
if ( !this.isPermission('createEvent_rrss', true)) {
  this.entityForm.controls.createEvent_rrss.disable();
}
```

cuando es un elemento de formulario no tengo problema alguno, con el entityForm lo selecciono directamente, pero como puedo seleccionar un elemento externo a un formulario dentro del html como puede ser un botón fuera de formulario?

```
<button 
[disabled]="!isPermission('addChannelButton', true)"
mat-raised-button 
class="o-btn o-btn--block"
color="primary"
(click)="onCreate2()">Agregar</button>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, imagino que es algo bastante básico a lo que no llego

Comment: Ésa es la única manera de hacerlo, a menos que quieras directamente no mostrar el elemento. En ese caso podrías usar `*ngIf ="condicion"`.

Comment: pero en caso de que no esté en un formulario entonces no tengo forma de hacerlo? que sugieres que use el entityForm aunque esté fuera de un formulario? el ngIf también lo hacemos, hacemos las 2 comprobaciones, una para mostrarlo y la otra para en caso de que se esté mostrando si tiene que estar disabled @PabloLozano

Comment: Puedes intentar con **ViewChild** y un **id** al checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se trata de rendimiento, lo que creo que te convendría sería usar una variable con la cual manejarla y que, a base de una función que no corra constantemente sino cuando lo deseemos, puedas ver el estado actual, poniendo esta función en los sitios donde se supone que alteran el estado:

EX:
.TS

```
canCheckbox: boolean = false // por defecto la pondremos falsa


// Con la que comprobaremos en ciertos sitios para saber el estado actual...
 permissionFunct(){

  this.canCheckbox = this.isPermission('createEvent_rrss', true)

 }
```

HTML

```
    <mat-checkbox 
[disabled]="canCheckbox">

    <!-- !isPermission('createEvent_rrss', true) -->
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad !, disculpa si no era lo que buscabas, de ser así hay más información para aportar, para una mayor comprensión?

**EDIT:** En los FormControl  el acercamiento podría ser este:

```
FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}) .
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!